# Homestead 502 Bad Gateway instead of Whoops for PHP errors

Tags: laravel, nginx, whoops

My Homestead Vagrant virtual machine is returning me a `502 Bad Gateway` instead of a Laravel Whoops error for some PHP errors (like class not found, some kind of parse errors etc ...).

Does someone have the solution for briging Whoops for all PHP errors ?

I could get the error reading manually `/var/log/nginx/<my_vhost>.app-error.log` like this :

`2014/11/27 15:15:44 [error] 1300#0: *12 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  <ERROR HERE> on line <LINE>`

But it is very annoying for debugging ...

Homestead version : 0.2.0.
Laravel version : 4.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some searches I found a working solution.

I have to add the following lines to my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` :

```
http {
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```

Dont forget to edit with root rights with `sudo`

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And then restart nginx

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Source of the info : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/whoops-doesnt-show-any-errors-homestead-20

Answer (score 0):

my homestead was showing this because of php fpm package . so i run this comment and now working fine

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm  --fix-missing
```